# Copy/Paste from one workbook to another is returning 0s and not actual values

Tags: vba, excel

My code activates the correct workbooks when needed but will only return 0s for the values instead of returning the actual values which are numbers and dates. I am also needing to close the DailyPerformance workbook after the data transfer is complete.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
TrackingReport = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Dim xDate As Double
Dim ACD As Double
Dim Untouched As Double
Dim DailyAct As Double
Dim SchedAdherence As Double
Dim Status As Double
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim DailyPerformance As Excel.Workbook


Set DailyPerformance = Workbooks.Open("P:\DX\Daily Team Performance\Dignositc Team's Daily Performance Tracker (001).xlsx", Password:="dailyp123")


Worksheets("1359 Report").Select
xDate = Range("L2").Value
Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Select
ACD = Range("C4").Value
Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Select
DailyAct = Range("E4").Value
Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Select
SchedAdherence = Range("F4").Value
Worksheets("1359 Report Summary").Select
Status = Range("B5").Value

Workbooks(TrackingReport).Activate
Set TrackinReport = ActiveWorkbook
Worksheets("Data").Select
Worksheets("Data").Range("B1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Data").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Data").Range("B1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = xDate
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = ACD
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = DailyAct
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = SchedAdherence
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = Status

End With
Workbooks(TrackingReport).Save



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try avoiding the use of select and instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, use `ThisWorkbook`. The `ActiveWorkbook` is the one "on top". The `ThisWorkbook` is where the vba code is executing.

Since I have no data to test this, I assume your references are right. For example, you really want xDate as `Double` (A number like x,xx) and not like `Date`? Same as Status. You could check this later.

If you have any questions about the code, please ask.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim xDate As Double
Dim ACD As Double
Dim Untouched As Double
Dim DailyAct As Double
Dim SchedAdherence As Double
Dim Status As Double
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim DailyPerformance As Excel.Workbook
Dim TWb As Workbook
Set TWb = ThisWorkbook
Set DailyPerformance = Workbooks.Open("P:\DX\Daily Team Performance\Dignositc Team's Daily Performance Tracker (001).xlsx", Password:="dailyp123")

xDate = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("1359 Report").Range("L2").Value
ACD = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("C4").Value
DailyAct = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("E4").Value
SchedAdherence = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("F4").Value
Status = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("1359 Report Summary").Range("B5").Value

RowCount = TWb.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Row
With TWb.Worksheets("Data").Range("B1")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = xDate
    .Offset(RowCount, 1) = ACD
    .Offset(RowCount, 2) = DailyAct
    .Offset(RowCount, 3) = SchedAdherence
    .Offset(RowCount, 4) = Status
End With
TWb.Save
DailyPerformance.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Moacir - Your code corrections work great. I am still needing to verify my changes to xdate populate properly. Will have to let you know how that goes once the report is run for Friday.

Answer (score 1):

Another Version

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim xlApp
Dim DailyPerformance

 Dim xDate As String
 Dim ACD As String
 Dim Untouched As String
 Dim DailyAct As String
 Dim SchedAdherence As String
 Dim Status As String
 Dim RowCount As Integer

Dim TrackingReport as Workbook



TrackingReport = ThisWorkbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True ' if you want it to be visible
Set DailyPerformance = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("P:\DX\Daily Team Performance\Dignositc Team's Daily Performance Tracker (001).xlsx", Password:="dailyp123")

DailyPerformance.Activate

xDate = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("1359 Report").Range("L2").Value

ACD = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("C4").Value

DailyAct = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("E4").Value

SchedAdherence = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("F4").Value

Status = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("1359 Report Summary").Range("B5").Value


TrackingReport.Activate
RowCount = TrackingReport.Worksheets("Data").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With TrackingReport.Worksheets("Data").Range("B1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = xDate
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = ACD
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = DailyAct
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = SchedAdherence
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = Status
End With


TrackingReport.save
DailyPerformance.close SaveChanges:=False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your declarations from `Double` to `String`. Also you don't have to do so many selects.

try this...

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    TrackingReport = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Dim xDate As String
    Dim ACD As String
    Dim Untouched As String
    Dim DailyAct As String
    Dim SchedAdherence As String
    Dim Status As String
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim DailyPerformance As Excel.Workbook

    Set DailyPerformance = Workbooks.Open("P:\DX\Daily Team Performance\Dignositc Team's Daily Performance Tracker (001).xlsx", Password:="dailyp123")

    xDate = Worksheets("1359 Report").Range("L2").Value
    ACD = Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("C4").Value
    DailyAct = Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("E4").Value
    SchedAdherence = Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("F4").Value
    Status = Worksheets("1359 Report Summary").Range("B5").Value

    Workbooks(TrackingReport).Activate

    Set TrackinReport = ActiveWorkbook
    RowCount = Worksheets("Data").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With Worksheets("Data").Range("B1")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0) = xDate
        .Offset(RowCount, 1) = ACD
        .Offset(RowCount, 2) = DailyAct
        .Offset(RowCount, 3) = SchedAdherence
        .Offset(RowCount, 4) = Status
    End With

    Workbooks(TrackingReport).Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using variant array method, edit Moacir code. Above codes is good. Only confer this code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim DailyPerformance As Workbook
Dim TWb As Workbook
Dim vR(1 To 5) As Variant '<~~ variant array

Set TWb = ThisWorkbook
Set DailyPerformance = Workbooks.Open("P:\DX\Daily Team Performance\Dignositc Team's Daily Performance Tracker (001).xlsx", Password:="dailyp123")
With DailyPerformance
vR(1) = .Worksheets("1359 Report").Range("L2").Value
vR(2) = .Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("C4").Value
vR(3) = .Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("E4").Value
vR(4) = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("F4").Value
vR(5) = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("1359 Report Summary").Range("B5").Value

RowCount = TWb.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
TWb.Worksheets("Data").Range("B" & RowCount).Resize(1, 5) = vR
TWb.Save
DailyPerformance.Close (0)

End Sub
```